# Using JSON templates in Play 2.0

Tags: json, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm getting this error:

> Compilation error [package views.json.Runs does not exist]

when it clearly does exist. I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong.

the action in the `Runs` controller:

```
@BodyParser.Of(play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result view(Long task_id, Long run_id) {
    Run run = Run.find.byId(run_id);
    return ok(views.json.Runs.view.render(run));
}
```

`app/views/Runs/view.scala.json`:

```
@(run: Run)

{
    "started": "@run.started",
    "completed": "@run.completed"
}
```

I've gotten a few html templates working, but this is the first JSON template I've tried with 2.0. I'm not sure what else to try since it's already about as basic as possible. Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**: I've gotten several suggestions for workarounds, but I'm still interested in knowing how to get the templates working, if only to better understand the changes to 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only html, xml and txt appear to be supported by default. For other file extensions and formats, you'd have to register additional "templateTypes" in `$PLAY_HOME/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala` (see also: [SBT Settings](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SBTSettings), near the bottom).

It may be helpful to look at the standard template types definitions which are in `$PLAY_HOME/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/templates/Templates.scala`.

You could also cheat and serve your json from a txt file, but do `response().setContentType("application/json")` before calling the `render` method.

Comment: Nice work finding a solid reference to back up your answer. That's as conclusive as I could hope for.

Answer (score 3):

For Json, why don't you directly produce a Json string using the [Json helper](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/libs/Json.html):

```
public static Result view(Long task_id, Long run_id) {
    Run run = Run.find.byId(run_id);
    return ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(run));
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the infinite recursion error I get. In `Run` I've got `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE) public Task task;` and in `Task` I've got `@OneToMany(mappedBy="task",fetch=FetchType.LAZY) public List<Run> runs;`. Quite possibly I'm doing something wrong there but I haven't figured out what yet.

Comment: It is not a good practice to have bidirectionnal relationships. Instead, write a method "getRuns()" in the Task bean which make a SQL query to retrieve the "Runs".

Comment: I eliminated the `Task.runs` field, but the infinite recursion still occurs when the `getRuns` method exists. Works find if I remove the method too. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Clearing the cache seems to have taken care of it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following the documentation and let the Json library serialize your data instead of writing the Json text on your own: [See Serving Json Response](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaJsonRequests).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since links tend to change, you're encouraged to include relevant excerpts from the linked page along with the link.

Comment: Oh thanks. This is their official versioned documentation, so that's pretty safe, but I'll remember to do that next time (aka too lazy right now)! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand, why does people want to render theirs JSON with views.

Note: this is the same way as  @nico_ekito showed before and I agree with him totally , below code just demonstrates how to select part of the object for JSON

```
public static Result view(Long task_id, Long run_id){

    Run run = Run.find.byId(run_id);

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("started", run.started);
    result.put("completed", run.completed);

    return ok(Json.toJson(result));

}
```

Comment: It does have the benefit of consistency when html and/or xml are also supported, and it allows Play to respond in the correct format automatically.

Comment: It lost the benefits, when you placing JSON in the template, as you need to worry about every comma, colon, bracket etc. etc. I tried it once, and never again ;) especially that I wanted to create really large API. loops in, loops, in loops. Of course using the ObjectNode you also need to iterate something, sometimes, but you don't need to search the template for forgotten bracket.